# GCP Private IP change for instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, cloud

In GCP if an instance is having an private ip does the private ip change if we restart or stop and start the instance. And also if it does not change what is the use of reserving a static internal ip address. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [restriction](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#restrictions) `You cannot unassign or change the internal IPv4 address of an existing resource`

Reserving an internal IP address takes that address out of the dynamic allocation pool and prevents it from being used for automatic allocations.

If a VM instance requires a [fixed Internal IP Address to a Static one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#:%7E:text=fixed%20internal%20IP%20address%20that%20does%20not%20change), you can also reserve it. Each VM interface has one primary internal IPv4 address, which is assigned from the subnet's primary IPv4 range.

With the ability to reserve static internal IP addresses, you can always use the [same IP address for the same resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address#before-you-begin:%7E:text=With%20the%20ability%20to%20reserve%20static%20internal%20IP%20addresses%2C%20you%20can%20always%20use%20the%20same%20IP%20address%20for%20the%20same%20resource%20even%20if%20you%20have%20to%20delete%20and%20recreate%20the%20resource.) even if you have to delete and recreate the resource.
Deleting a resource does not automatically release a static internal IP address.